# How can I convert Markdown string to normal HTML in Vue 3 (Options API approach)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, markdown, chatgpt-api

I am a backend developer and trying to get a foot onto vuejs.

I am trying to write a frontend, which contacts the OpenAI API and gives back reponses from GPT-4.
This works perfectly fine, but GPT-4 also returns reponses in markdown.

I cannot find out how to do that in my specific case.

I tried to use the following npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-markdown
After using this in my code, I get the following (Please don't judge the design ): [screenshot of result with the vue-markdown npm package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBkEJ.png)

Here is the code I wrote in my Chat.vue file:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { GPTMessage } from '../types/GPTMessage';
import { ChatAPI } from '../lib/gpt';
import VueMarkdown from 'vue-markdown-render'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chatHistory: [] as GPTMessage[],
      input: "" as string
    }
  },
  components: {
    VueMarkdown
  },
  methods: {
    async askGpt(): Promise<void> {
      this.chatHistory.push({ role: "user", content: this.input })
      this.input = ""
      const resp = await ChatAPI(this.chatHistory)
      this.chatHistory.push({ role: resp.role, content: resp.content })
    },
    handleChange(event: any) {
      this.input = event.target.value
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col h-screen justify-between mb-auto">
    <div class="mb-auto">
      <vue-markdown v-for="message in chatHistory">{{ message.content }}</vue-markdown>
    </div>
    <div class="flex mt-5">
      <button @click="askGpt">Chat</button>
      <input type="text" class="bg-red-500 w-full" @change="handleChange" :value="input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you import and register the component?

Comment: If it was not imported and registered, content in the slot simply "passes through", like in your screenshot.

Comment: And now that the code is updated, the screenshots and such are almost certainly incorrect. I think that actually should have been the main part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to loop through each message with the content and render it in the markdown like so :

```
<div v-for="message in chatHistory" :key="message.content">
    <vue-markdown :source="message.content"></vue-markdown>
</div>
```

Comment: After trying that, no content is shown. Not my message and also not the message of GPT.

Comment: Did you import the component? If it was not imported and registered, putting the content in the slot would allow it to "pass through" when the component itself wasn't processed (e.g., your screenshot). Using a prop, like here, would mean nothing at all would be rendered (except the `div`s) if the component was not registered.

Comment: @shan Could you please update the code in your question to reflect that change?